# Both GPUs on Titan Z seem to use the same global memory?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda

I'm working on a programme that uses both GPUs on the Titan Z, and it works fine when the total amount of memory allocated is less than 6 GB(i.e <3GB on each card).

However when I use more than 6 GB there are incredibly long stalls between any CUDA launches, doesn't matter how much memory is allocated on each GPU, if the combine amount is >6 GB the performance drops to nothing because of the stalls.

Upon inspecting the amount of memory available with cudaMemGetInfo() I find that both GPUs have the same amount. Test code as follow

```
for(int j=0; j<gnum; j++)
{
    cudaSetDevice(j);
    cudaMemGetInfo(&freeMemory, &totalMemory);
    printf("Device memory = %lli \n", totalMemory);
    printf("Available memory = %lli \n", freeMemory);
}
for(int i=0; i<gnum; i++)
{
    cudaSetDevice(i);
    cudaMalloc(&d[i], 1024*1024*1024);
    for(int j=0; j<gnum; j++)
    {
        cudaSetDevice(j);
        cudaMemGetInfo(&freeMemory, &totalMemory);
        printf("Device memory = %lli \n", totalMemory);
        printf("Available memory = %lli \n", freeMemory);
    }
}
```

and I get

```
Device memory = 644250944
GPU 0 Available memory = 5272363008
Device memory = 644250944
GPU 1 Available memory = 5195358208
GPU 0 Available memory = 4121616384
GPU 1 Available memory = 4121616384
GPU 0 Available memory = 3047874560
GPU 1 Available memory = 3047874560
```

So it appears that both GPUs are using the same 6GB of memory instead of one on each of 6GB memory. I'm using Windows 8.1 64bits and using WDDM if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Make sure you have SLI _disabled_ in NVIDIA control panel.